# Prolific USB-to-serial communication port is significantly slower under Windows 7 compared to Windows XP

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, usb, serial-port

I am using a Prolific USB-to-Serial adapter based on the Prolific chip to use with a device on serial port. I have the latest version of the driver installed: 1.3.0 (2010-7-15).

When I use my device with this adapter on my main Windows 7 (32 bit) system, it takes 8-9 seconds to send a command through to the device. However, when I do the same thing on a different Windows XP system (an old laptop I borrowed for testing) it only takes 2-3 seconds. I have made sure that the port settings and other variables are the same between systems. I also tested on a third laptop (also running Windows 7) and again got a significant delay.

Is there a solution? I would like to avoid moving to an Windows XP system for what I need to achieve, so that's my last option.

Comment: I ended up purchasing a ATEN UC2322 2-Port USB-to-Serial RS-232 Hub and using it on Win7 with official Vista driver to achieve acceptable speed. It still doesn't solve the original issue though.